# RequireJS + Zepto + Waypoints: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-waypoints, zepto

I am trying to use [`waypoints`](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) with `zepto` and `RequireJS`.

My requireJS configuration looks like this:

```
requirejs : {
options : {
    baseUrl : '<%= config.app.js %>',
    paths : {
        almond : '../node_modules/almond/almond',
        zepto : '../node_modules/zepto/zepto.min',
        'progressbar' : '../node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar',
        waypoints : '../node_modules/waypoints/lib/zepto.waypoints'
    },
    shim : {
        zepto : {
            exports : '$'
        }
    },
    mainConfigFile: '<%= config.app.js %>/common.js',
    include : ['common'],
    name : 'almond',
    out : 'dist/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js', 
    insertRequire: ['common'],
    wrap: true
},
dist : {
    options : {
        optimize: 'uglify2'
    }
},
dev : {
    options : {
        optimize: 'none'
    }
}
},
```

Furthermore, my `common.js` file is as follows:

```
define(['zepto', 'waypoints'], function($) {

var waypoint = $('#experience').waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {}
});
```

});

But when the page is loaded, I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

The error, comes from this line on the `waypoints` plugin library:

`return this.$element[method].apply(this.$element, args)`

When I debug the code, I can see that `function ZeptoAdapter(element)` is called twice, once with `$('#experience')` as element, and once with `window`. The second time is when it fails, since `this.$element` is undefined. Am I doing something wrong? What's the proper way of including a zepto plugin?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints doesn't do anything to export for CommonJS or AMD. I believe you need to shim it as well:

```
shim : {
  zepto : {
    exports : '$'
  },
  waypoints: {
    deps: ['zepto'],
    exports: 'Waypoint'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solve my problem

```
shim : {
    jqueryWaypoints:{
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jqueryWaypoints'
   }
}
```